# Quickly get all emails sent to a specific receiver in a huge catch-all inbox(>100k emails)

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, pop3

I have a catch-all email. It means emails going to *john@domain.com*, *bob@domain.com*, *girl@domain.com*, etc. goes to a single inbox *catchall@domain.com*. There are > 100k emails in there and growing. I need to quickly get all emails sent for a specific email, e.g. *bob@domain.com*. I tried this(using Javamail):

```
SearchTerm searchTerm = new RecipientTerm(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(username + "@domain.com"));
Message[] msgs = inbox.search(searchTerm);
```

Bu it is too slow, 10 mins went by, still searching... I see a `fetch` method, but not sure how to use it. Could it be used somehow?

Any suggestions on how could I solve it?

Comment: POP3 does not have remote search.  If you wish to do remote searches, you will need to use IMAP.

Comment: Exactly.  POP3 requires that all the messages are downloaded to the client and searched there.  IMAP allows you to send the search request to the server; the server does the searching and returns the list of matching messages.  The [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) will show you what's going on in either case.

Comment: @Max How can I do it with IMAP?

Comment: Exactly what you'e doing here, except connect to an IMAP server with IMAP instead.  JavaMail works the same way, but can rely on the server for features.